# list/consult Taxonomy only for the respective author/creator in dashbboard

Tags: customization, custom-taxonomy, custom-field, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to filter so that only the creators of the respective categories can edit them.
I created a `cat_author` meta field and associated it to the taxonomy.
In this way, every taxonomy has an author. And I tended to filter with

```
add_filter( 'pre_get_terms', 'filter_cat_by_u_id', 99, 1 );
function filter_cat_by_u_id( $query ) {
    if ( ! is_admin() ) {
      return $query;
    }
    global $pagenow;    
    if ( 'edit-tags.php' === $pagenow ) {
        $meta_query = array(
            array(
                'key' => 'cat_author',
                'value' => get_current_user_id(),
                'compare' => '='
            )
        );
        $query->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );
    }
    return $query;
}
```

But I'm not getting a good result. Does anyone have any tips?

UPDATE:

```
add_filter( 'get_terms_args', 'filter_cat_by_u_id' );
function filter_cat_by_u_id( $args ) {
    global $pagenow;

    if ( is_admin() && 'edit-tags.php' === $pagenow ) {
        $args['meta_query'] = array( 
            array(
                'key' => 'cat_author',
                'value' => get_current_user_id(),
                'compare' => '='
            )
        );
    }

    return $args;
}
```

Thanks to Sally I this solution works perfectly fine to filter the list of custom categories in wp-admin/dahsboar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`WP_Term_Query` class](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_term_query/) doesn't have a method named `set`, and calling `$query->set()` in my case resulted in a fatal/critical error saying "*Call to undefined method WP_Term_Query::set()*". :/

But you can directly modify the `query_vars` property (i.e. `$query->query_vars`), like so, to set, unset or override any query variables like `meta_query`:

```php
// Use this:
$query->query_vars['meta_query'] = $meta_query;

// NOT this (which causes a fatal error):
$query->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );
```

Or you could instead use the [`get_terms_args` hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/get_terms_args/):

```php
add_filter( 'get_terms_args', 'filter_cat_by_u_id' );
function filter_cat_by_u_id( $args ) {
    global $pagenow;

    if ( is_admin() && 'edit-tags.php' === $pagenow ) {
        $args['meta_query'] = array( your code here );
    }

    return $args;
}
```

Comment: Ty so much Sally. You save me!